# LED radiation angle appears to be changing with distance

Tags: led

I am trying to measure the radiation angle of an LED.

Below are my measurements which I've gone over many times:

`d` is the distance between the tip of the LED and a sheet of paper.

`r` is the radius of the spot reflected from the paper.

`a` is the angle calculated from r and d (arctan(r/d).

- d = 200 mm, r = 45 mm, so a = 12.6
- d = 150 mm, r = 35 mm, so a = 13.1
- d = 100 mm, r = 25 mm, so a = 14.0
- d = 50 mm, r = 8.5 mm, so a = 9.6
- d = 25 mm, r = 7.5 mm, so a = 16.6

So the angle appears to be changing with distance. I've tried several LEDs and the same happens (different measurements, but the angles still appears to change with distance).

The measurements above (d & r) are certainly correct. I've gone over them many times. Am I calculating the angle incorrectly (arctan(r/d))? The LEDs should radiate a cone of light, and this appears to be the case when I observe the light beam with a sheet of paper positioned in parallel to the LED (I see the light take the form of a triangle on the paper), so I should be able to calculate the angle with arctan(). Also, when measuring the radius of the spot on the paper, the spot takes the form of a circle, which would suggest it is a cone of light.

The measurements above were taken from this LED: [C503B-RAN-CA0B0AA1](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/cree-inc/C503B-RAN-CA0B0AA1/C503B-RAN-CA0B0AA1-ND/4793651) ([datasheet](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/C503B-RAS-RAN-AAS-AAN-RBS-RBN-ABS-ABN-RCS-RCN-ACS-ACN-1079.pdf))

Where am I going wrong please?

Comment: How are you measuring the radius of the spot?  Is it possible the change in brightness with distance is affecting how accuracy of the measurement?

Comment: ah, you're confusing the LED with a point source and the body of the LED with lens in ray optics. Neither model assumptions apply here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I understand an LED isn't a true point source but we should still be able to calculate the radiation angle with trig(?). I read this here: https://www.newport.com/n/focusing-and-collimating.

Comment: Think about what makes the "edge" of your illumination circle look unsharp and fuzzy. Does that in any way fit in the model of optics that the site you link to describe?

Comment: By the way, the fact alone that it's not a point source allows to explain non-monotonic overall spot radius over distance.

Comment: @jonathanjo I'm using a digital caliper to measure the diameter of the spot, then calculating the radius from that.

Comment: @JohnO'brien the digital caliper *itself* is not a measurement device for light – *you* are the one saying "oh, that's the spot", and then measure the diameter of that. Jonathan is right – the fact that the intensity has to go down (squaredly!) with the distance isn't great on humans' ability to judge diameter reliably. At which brightness do you "draw the line" between "part of the spot" and "dark"? Remember that intensity perception is **not** linear or square in nature, but mostly logarithmic.

Comment: @MarcusMüller So when I move the LED closer to the sheet of paper, with the LED turned on, and I see the spot diameter decrease, are you saying that my perception of the boundary of the spot is changing?

Comment: A combination of the non-ray optics, the non-spot light source and your perception at work, yes.

Comment: If you are attempting to verify the specification in the datasheet, it says "far field pattern". So, they are measuring at a large distance, much greater than 200 mm. And they use the 50% brightness point as the threshold. You may be using something closer to 90%. Go in a dark room and measure at 1 meter and 2 meters, the angle should be almost the same. Note that the spec is 15 deg.

Comment: @JohnO'brien, the emissive area is not necessarily round ... it may actually be rectangular

Comment: @jsotola that's interesting, could you please provide a link for further reading on that? Or just a keyword I can lookup

Comment: @JohnO'brien The LED article on wikipedia actually has a close-up photo of an LED die.

Comment: @JohnO'brien, i determined the shape of the lit area in an LED through personal observation

Answer (score 2):

> So the angle appears to be changing with distance. I've tried several LEDs and the same happens (different measurements, but the angles still appears to change with distance).

That is normal.  You're trying to measure something like the FWHM diameter of an extended source from a short distance.  Since each point on the source is emitting light over a range of angles (which are not necessarily the same), as you measure the approximate edge of the sum of those emissions, you're going to get different values depending on how they overlap at each distance.

> The LEDs should radiate a cone of light, and this appears to be the case when I observe the light beam with a sheet of paper positioned in parallel to the LED (I see the light take the form of a triangle on the paper), so I should be able to calculate the angle with arctan().

A single mode laser would radiate a cone of light.  This is an LED, and you are much too close to approximate it as a point source, so its radiating a huge number of different cones, each spatially offset from each other.  So yes,  you can measure that angle with arctan(), but it won't be constant.

What are you actually doing?  Is an LED the right light source for your project?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to design an acrylic lens to collimate the light from the LED. I need to know the angle of the light source in order calculate the focal length of the lens. It seems that I just need to calculate the angle at the predefined distance and use that instead of using the viewing angle from the datasheet. Is that correct?

Comment: @JohnO'brien no, that is not correct. You're oversimplifying what your lens need to do: the LED light source simply can't be modeled by a single angle.

Comment: @JohnO'brien LED light cannot be collimated.  If you really need a collimated beam, you'll need to use a laser.  Do you need collimation, or is it enough to just focus the LED light down?  What are you actually doing?

Comment: What does "FWHM" mean?

Comment: @jonathanjo Full width, half maximum.  It is a measure that can be used to define the width of a continuous function or distribution, and very roughly corresponds to the visual width of an illuminated spot.

Comment: @JohnO'brien Everyone is trying to tell you, basically, that you don't really understand optics very well. And if you are trying to design a collimating lens, that's not a good sign. You can collimate a point source. You cannot collimate something with a wide spatial emitter area from the perspective of your collimating lens. The best you can hope for is some kind of "least confusing collimation" of some measure you decide on. Or move your lens really far away so the source appears to be a point source (which usually defeats the goals.) Some flashlights illustrate this "least confusing" idea.

Comment: If you don't really need a collimated beam, if you only want to narrow the beam somewhat, try something like a 38 mm dia, 5 cm focal length, double convex lens. With a common white LED, I can get the cone to about 3 degrees. At sharpest focus, the spot brightness is not very uniform, you will probably want to de-focus slightly.